# Hide script extension

Tags: python, web-applications, cgi

I have a html form that posts to a python script test.py. If someone tries to access the script directly, it redirects them to the form.

I not using a web framework, just straight python cgi programming. My website is hosted on a shared hosting provider that allows me access to a .htaccess file.

I wanted to know if there was a way to have the form post to the script and in the address bar show mydomain.com/test/ and not mydomain.com/test.py ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/test/$ /test.py
```

Comment: and should the form post to just "/test"

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to rewrite the URL as desired.